# How can I open every file in a given directory using a batch or vbs script?

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I have a static directory, but dynamic files. I want to write a batch file that scans the directory and automatically opens any file that gets dropped in there. I would prefer to do it with a batch or vbs script, although open to anything at this point. I've tried a bunch of things and nothing seems to work quite the way I want it to——please help!

Comment: what does it mean to "open [a] file"? What are you _really_ going to do with the files? Send them to photoshop? Print them? Email them? Encrypt them? ...

Comment: What has this to do with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this in a bat file

```
for %%i in (c:\temp\*.*) do start %%i
```

to open all the files using the file association.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I needed. Gahh, I had tried things so close to that. Thank you so much!